# Invoke Google Cloud Function with Parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to pass a parameter "env" while triggering/invoking a cloud function using Scheduler with http.

I am using a service account that has sufficient permissions for invoking functions and admin rights on Scheduler.

Passing the parameter works when the function allows un-authenticated invocation, but if the function is deployed with authentication it gives an error: { "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" ....

It is worth noting that when I changed the function code that it does not require a parameter, it worked successfully with the same service account.

So, it must be an issue with passing parameters.

The scheduler job setup looks like this:

[image]

The way I retrieve the parameter "env" in the function is as

```
def fetchtest(request):

    env = request.args.get('env')
```

Comment: You cannot include query parameters when specifying the OIDC `Audience`. The identity specified affects the Identity Token generated and not the URL that Cloud Scheduler calls.

Comment: Is there a reason you're invoking the function over HTTP? Using Pub/Sub and a background function would keep everything Google-internal and would allow you to specify arbitrary values in the message.

Comment: I agree both with Jhon and Dustin, if you are going to authenticate your function why not use oauth token? Also using pub/sub could be a lot cleaner and safer. If your use case have any aspect that we can be missing please edit your question and add the aditional information